# linux: how to show permission of files (like ls -l) does on files returned by the find command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, permissions, find

I am doing a find command to show me the files of a specific extension, like:

`find $directory -type f -name "*.vm"`

however I would like to be able to see the file permissions as well (like ls -l shows) .

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `find` has a `-ls` directive you can use. It has an output format quite close to but not exactly matching that of `ls -l`.

The default action of find, if none is given, is `-print` which simply prints the file name and path as found. If you add (or replace `-print` with) `-ls` then you get a more verbose listing.

If you want some particular format for whatever reason, `-printf` is what you want. For example, try this:

```
find . -printf "%M %n %8.8u %8.8g %8.8s %Ax %AX %p\n"
```

to approximately replicate the `ls -l` output format. (That uses a different date formatting; it might be possible to replicate the behavior of ls there as well; see the `find` man page for details on the formatting specifiers available, and `printf(3)` for details on what the numbers do.)

Generally, you want to **avoid** using `-exec` if you can, and if you have to use -exec, you **want** to try to use `+` rather than `{}` to give multiple file names in a single invocation. Otherwise the command will be executed once per file found matching the criteria, which with large numbers of files can come at a substantial performance penalty.

Also note that if you don't need the recursion behavior, the simplest solution might be to just use ls in the first place: `ls -ld $directory/*.vm`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `-ls` option to `find`. Or, if you need a specific format, use `-exec`:

```
find "$directory" -type f -name '*.vm'  -exec ls -l {} \;
```